# Delay or Sleep function in NativeScript/Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

My Sleep/Delay function doesnt work.

I tried using the 'rxjs/operators' delay function but it didn't work.

My Code:

```
sentence: string = "Hallo"

wordToMorse(sentence: any) {
        for (var char of sentence) {
            if (char != " ") {
                this.vibrateWord(char);
                this.delay(1000);

            } else {
                this.delay(1000);
            }

        }
    }

vibrateWord(character: any) {
        if (character == "H") {
            this.vibrator.vibrate(500);
        } else if (character == "a") {
            this.vibrator.vibrate(1000);
        } else if (character == "l") {
            this.vibrator.vibrate(500);
        } else if (character == "o") {
            this.vibrator.vibrate(2000);
        }
    }

async delay(ms: number) {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(()=>resolve(), ms)).then(()=>console.log("fired"));
    }
```

What i expect to happen is that after every vibration for the letter in the sentence, it should wait for 1 second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have placed the `aysnc await` at the wrong place, try this:

```
async wordToMorse(sentence: any) { // <------ Change
    for (var char of sentence) {
        if (char != " ") {
            this.vibrateWord(char);
            await this.delay(1000); // <------ Change

        } else {
            await this.delay(1000); // <------ Change
        }

    }
}

delay(ms: number) { // <------ Change
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(()=>resolve(), ms)).then(()=>console.log("fired")); // <------ Change
}
```

Comment: @SwaX, Glad to know, Happy coding BTW :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a clean way to do this using Observables:

```js
from(sentence.split('')).pipe(
      take(sentence.length),
      concatMap(letter => of(letter).pipe(delay(1000))),
      tap(letter => {
        // vibrate logic here
      })
    ).subscribe();
```

Comment: `from` creates an Observable from an Array, emitting each value in turn. The `take` means you don't have to worry about subscriptions. `concatMap` queues up incoming emissions, waiting until each child Observable is complete. The `of` creates a new Observable from each letter, which is then delayed by a second.